# Program throws exceptions inside my Do/While loop

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

I am very new to programming, and am working on an assignment practicing do/while loops and switch statements. I've written out a program listing Museum Hours and it compiles, but I can't seem to get it to function properly. It just throws:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MuseumHours {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    //variables
    String day;
    boolean holiday = true;
    String userContinue;
    String monday = "Closed";
    //end variables

    //begin program

    do {

    System.out.println("Hello! Thank you for visiting the museum's website. For what day would you like to view our hours of operation?");
    day = stdIn.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Is today a holiday?");
    holiday = stdIn.nextBoolean();

    switch (day) {

        case "Monday":
            System.out.println(monday);
        case "Tuesday":
            if (holiday !=true) {
                System.out.println("The museum is open from 12:00 to 4:00.");
            } else { 
                System.out.println("The museum is open from 1:00 to 3:00.");
                }
            break;
        case "Wednesday":
            if (holiday !=true) {
                System.out.println("The museum is open from 12:00 to 4:00.");
            } else { 
                System.out.println("The museum is open from 1:00 to 3:00.");
                }
            break;
        case "Thursday":
            if (holiday != true) {
                System.out.println("Today the museum opens from 10:00 to 5:00.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Today the museum opens from 11:00 to 4:00.");
                }
            break;
        case "Friday":
            if (holiday != true) {
                System.out.println("Today the museum opens from 10:00 to 5:00.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Today the museum opens from 11:00 to 4:00.");
                }
            break;

        case "Saturday":   
            if (holiday != true) {
                System.out.println("Today the museum is open from 9:00 to 6:00.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Today the museum is open from 10:00 to 5:00.");
                }
            break;
        case "Sunday":
            if (holiday != true) {
                System.out.println("Today the museum is open from 9:00 to 6:00.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Today the museum is open from 10:00 to 5:00.");
                }
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid day.");

            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to run the program again? Enter Y for yes, or N for no.");
            userContinue = stdIn.nextLine();
        } while (userContinue.equals("Y"));
    }
}
```

Comment: _It just throws:_.. what exception are you getting?

Comment: What exception is being thrown and for which input?

Comment: You missed break statement after Monday

Comment: works for me without exceptions. you are missing some `break` statements in some cases but it runs

Comment: Please, provide the exceptions. And please, if holiday is boolean don't use (holyday != true), just do (!holiday)

Comment: When I try to test my "closed" hours for Monday, I get this code (I get the same code for any day I try, however. 
I am not sure how to interpret this?

Hello! Thank you for visiting the museum's website. For what day would you like to view our hours of operation?
Monday
Is today a holiday?
N
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1782)
 at MuseumHours.main(MuseumHours.java:21)

Comment: Okay, so what I have found on this so far is that it my boolean 'holiday' is not accepting Y/N, it is only accepting true or false. I understand why this is... I never told it anywhere to accept Y or N. So, now I've at least got a direction!

Answer (score 1):

The exception can be when you are not passing the right type of arguments from command line at the execution time.

For example, the below line gives you error in case any value passed for "Is today a holiday?" question is different from any of these (true, false), case insensitive.

holiday = stdIn.nextBoolean();

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch
>   statement's expression

if your are not using java SE 7 and later you can't run this program

also you code can improve by replacing

```
if(holiday != true){...}
```

to

```
if(!holiday){...}
```